# Double Tap on UITableViewCell

Tags: uitableview

I want to get a single tap as well as double tap on a `UITableViewCell`. I have created a customDataSource for the `UITableview`.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 20):

The correct way to do this is to add your UITapGestureRecognizer on the tableView :

```
UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Then in your callback methods you find the cell with something like this :

```
-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:tap.view];
        NSIndexPath* indexPath = [_tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
        UITableViewCell* cell = [_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi , 
I tried this method, but whenever i double tapp on a cell, it always go into the single tap's method.
It never goes to double Tap function.
I have written exactly same code which you have provided.
please help.

Comment: To get this to work you also need to disable user interaction on the cell. This will stop the cell eating the single tap before the table's gesture recognisers get a chance to do their work.

Comment: If you disable user interaction, how do you scroll?

Comment: You shouldn't disable `userInteractionEnabled`, but rather `allowsSelection`

Comment: CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:tap.view];
Should be         CGPoint p = [tap locationInView:_tableView];

Answer (score 7):

I have achieved this by adding the following to your gesture recognizer, although I find that there's a slight delay when single tapping.

```
[tapRecognizer setDelaysTouchesBegan:YES];
[tapRecognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

you forgot about [doubleTap release];

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];

doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

[cell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[doubleTap release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have this line in order to separate between single and double taps.
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap]; Here is the example code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // After cell initialized code
  //...
  //...

  UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
  doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

  UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doSingleTap:)];
  singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
  [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doDoubleTap];

  [cell addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
  [cell addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
  return cell;
}

-(void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
  NSLog(@"Double Taps");

  CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: point];
  UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  // do your stuff.
  // ...
}

-(void)singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
  NSLog(@"Single Tap");
  CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
  UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  // Do you stuff with index path or cell here.
  // ...

}
```

Comment: This is wrong !
Adding 2 recognizers to table view in viewDidLoad is enough. you are creating 2 x tableview.count recognizers!
If you have many cells, you take memory and UI responsiveness for nothing...

Answer (score -1):

Ok so this time I added Button on cell covering complete width and height.
and Using UIBUTTON touch event I have using it.

```
[btnCellReview addTarget:self action:@selector(multipleTap:withEvent:) 
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];

-(IBAction)multipleTap:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {    
UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
      // do action.    
}
}
```